# Отобразить цепочку редиректов в консоль google chrome

Tags: javascript, http, httpclient

Подскажите как в браузере посмотреть тройной редирект. Можно ли восстановить всю цепочку. Я вижу только последний.

Comment: Если только из браузера, то посмотрите историю

Comment: где это можно посмотреть в хроме?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Chrome Инструменты разработчика на вкладке Network ставим Preserve Log, тем самым заставим все запросы сохраняться в логе при загрузке последующих страниц.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]